# make two big number add by array in c code

Tags: c, addition

I want to construct two big number by array in c programming and make them add.

The following is my code:

```
void add(unsigned char* a, unsigned char* b, unsigned int len)
{
    int i;
    unsigned short T;
    unsigned char carry = 0;
    for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        T = (unsigned short)(a[i]) + (unsigned short)(b[i]) + (unsigned short)carry;
        //T = a[i] + b[i] + carry;
        if (T > 0xFF)
            carry = 1;
        else
            carry = 0;

        a[i] = (unsigned char)T;
    }
}
```

The max value in array a and b for every element is 255.

EDIT1: The highest carry is discarded. The result is save in array a.

EDIT2: replace "Byte" with "carry".

The original code is :

```
Integer B1(B, SM3_BLOCK_SIZE);
++B1;

for (i = 0; i < ILen; i += v)
  (Integer(I + i, v) + B1).Encode(I + i, v);
```

I write two new function. One is as the Above `add()`, The other is as following:

```
void add_one(unsigned char *arr, unsigned int len)
{
    int i;
    for (i = len-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        arr[len] += 1;
        if (arr[len] != 0) 
            return; 
    }
}
```

If my code is rigth, the original code is as following:

```
add_one(B, SM3_BLOCK_SIZE);
for (i = 0; i < ILen; i += v)
  add(I + i, B, SM3_BLOCK_SIZE);
```

Comment: Looks like it works.  Are you having a problem with it?

Comment: Tip: `carry` would be a better name than `Byte` for your var.

Comment: Re "*The highest carry is discarded.*", That only happens when `a` is too short. e.g. FFFF + FFFF returns FFFE, but 00FFFF + 00FFFF returns 01FFFE. You could use `return Byte;` so that the caller knows an overflow occurred.

Comment: when it is used whit other modules in my program, it always doesn't output correctly. I will add other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is (at least) one bug. Look at this code:

```
void add_one(unsigned char *arr, unsigned int len)
{
    int i;
    for (i = len-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        arr[len] += 1;        // Indexing using len is wrong
        if (arr[len] != 0)    // Indexing using len is wrong 
            return; 
    }
}
```

You probably want to use `i` as index.

Comment: Thanks, it work correctly. I don't believe there is a bug. My code is large. I  had never checked add_one() function.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you know that you are implementing the add function for a bigendian positive integer.

1. Avoid using  `for (i = len-1; i >= 0; --i)`. You can catch a runtime error when `i` is unsigned and `len` is 0. Instead, use `for (i = len; i-- > 0;)`.
2. If you need a little-endian integer than use `for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)`

```
char add(unsigned char* a, unsigned char* b, unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned short carry = 0;
    //for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) // for little-endian
    for (int i = len; i-- > 0;) // for big-endian
    {
        carry += a[i] + b[i];
        a[i] = carry & 0xFF;
        carry >>= 8;
    }
    return carry;
}
```

Tests

```
    unsigned char a[5] = {255,2,3,4,5};
    unsigned char b[5] = {255,256-2,256-3,4,5};
    char overflow = add(a,b,5);
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d / %d",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4] , overflow);
```

Output

```
255 1 0 8 10 / 1
```